# Format SQL query return col

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a col ProductName in my Select statement which has a String which has a attached string "-Sales" for e.g. peter -Sales. Now I want my result to remove that -Sales and just show peter. How can i do it.I am just pasting my select part of my query as my query has many inner join

```
SELECT
dbo.Customer.firstName+' '+dbo.Customer.lastName        AS FirstName,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dbo.Receipt.receiptDate,105)       AS SaleDate,
dbo.Receipt.transactionNumber AS TransactionNumber,
dbo.Receipt.description        AS ProductName,
```

Comment: [String Functions (Transac-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Comment: Will it always be `-Sales` or do you want to strip out everything after the ***last `-`***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `REPLACE`

```
SELECT REPLACE(dbo.Customer.firstName+' '+dbo.Customer.lastName, '-Sales',''),...
FROM...
```

- [T-SQL REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5544a/2)